# How to average/ensemble targets of 2 or more dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Say:

---

df1

IMG | isHotDogConfidence

img1| 0

img2| 1

img3| 0

img4| 0

img5| 1

---

df2

IMG | isHotDogConfidence

img1| 1

img2| 1

img3| 1

img4| 0

img5| 0

---

What I want:

IMG | isHotDogConfidence

img1| 0.5

img2| 1

img3| 0.5

img4| 0

img5| 0.5

How would you use pandas to do it efficiently?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with aggregate `mean`:

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2]).groupby('IMG', as_index=False).mean()
print (df)
    IMG  isHotDogConfidence
0  img1                 0.5
1  img2                 1.0
2  img3                 0.5
3  img4                 0.0
4  img5                 0.5
```